# ImportError: module incorrectly imported

Tags: python, django, docker, virtualenv

I am getting error when I run below given command

```
docker-compose run app python manage.py test

ImportError: 'tests' module incorrectly imported from '/app/core/tests'. Expected '/app/core'. Is this module globally installed?
```

Tried to import that from shell but still not working

```
>>> import app.core.tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.core'
```

Versions:

```
Django==2.1.3
djangorestframework==3.9.0
docker==3.7.2
docker-compose==1.24.0
docker-pycreds==0.4.0
dockerpty==0.4.1
docopt==0.6.2

Python 3.7.2
```

[image]

Comment: it should be `import core.tests` because your base dir is already `app`

Comment: Also you have tests.py and tests. That will give a conflict. Delete tests.py.

Answer (score 4):

As you want to use the `tests` folder instead of the `tests.py` file, you need to delete the latter so that they don't conflict. That way they should work.

Comment: Thank you. I have deleted the other `tests.py` file from the app I was testing and it worked. Cheers.